# OSX Titanium Mobile for IOS & android

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am an IOS developer with a working XCode 4 installation on Snow Leopard.
As such I don't currently have an android development environment installed as up to now I have not needed one.

I would like to evaluate appcellerator Titanium Mobile with a view to using it for prototyping a product for an end client who needs an app to be available on IOS & android, and from what I have read, this may be an appropriate way to go, and it may not, depending on the nature of the end product.

I have downloaded and installed the latest Titanium Studio and it appears to have picked up settings for my XCode installation, and would allow me to create a "hello world" app to build on that environment, however, as I don't have android, I naturally can't achieve what I would like to do, which is at a bare minimum, have a "hello world" app that I can build to the latest IOS and android version(s). ideally a selection of older versions of each flavour would be a nice have, but not absolutely essential at this stage.

I attempted to install the android SDK, which on the surface was successful, but Titanium won't pick it up. I consulted the appcellerator website (http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/mobile-build-osx) which appears on the surface to have the information I needed, however when I dig into it, from screenshots it appears to be very out of date, and I could not get the desired result)

So, pretending I have NO android SDK installed (ie there is nothing i need to particularly preserve about what i have attempted so far), what's the simplest path to get Titanium Studio ready to build for both IOS and android? Ie i need to do both simultaneously - if I wanted a pure IOS deployment I would not cripple my development by forcing myself to use javascript - I would code in objective C. if I wanted to develop purely for android I would not use Titanium either - the only real point in a product like Titanium for experienced programmers is to avoid double handling of coding tasks. I can see there is a secondary application where "javascript developers" (that is to say "web designers") may wish to use such a product to avoid the learning curve of objective C, but other than that, there must be a simple way to get this product building "cross platform" out of the box, or it serves no real purpose.

Finally, if you can't answer the question as posed, please refrain from evangelizing your particular stance on "roll your own" or "write 2 apps, don't use Titanium". I wish to evaluate Titanium and make up my own mind, and not rely on the opinions of others with a vested interest in preventing me from doing that. I have enough bias against the product already, however I am open minded enough to see if indeed it is useful as a cross platform development tool.

I am happy to post (using comments to this question) the results of my evaluation, if others find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the bits necessary for iOS, this should be straightforward. In Titanium, find the Dashboard. It should launch by default, but you can get to it from the button that has Appcelerator's logo. From there, click on the "Configure" tab and select Android. Once you've done that, you can install the Android SDK from Titanium directly, and there should be no confusion over path referencing. You'll need the core SDK, as well as Google APIs 8 and the emualtor for 2.2.

Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:
[image]

EDIT: 
I didn't notice the question date when I responded. I got here through a misclick and just jumped in. Sorry about that.